# Refresh the whole frame of parent window after the submit on popup

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The `pageA.php` is in the `<iframe>` and there is a link on `pageA.php` to display a popup window. After clicking the submit button on the popup window, I would like the popup window is closed and then the whole frame is refreshed.

I have tried the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['popupSubmit'])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.close();
        window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
    </script>";
}
```

However, the popup window did close but the whole frame doesn't get refreshed?

Comment: How exactly is the `window.top.location.href` line supposed to be executed _after_ the popup window closes? Once the window is closed, it's gone, and no subsequent JS runs.

Comment: if put window.top.location.href in front of window.close();, the pop up doesn't close.

Answer (score 0):

put this in the pop up file -

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

or if the frame doesn't refresh then you might need to use ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
</script>";
```